# Making international payments from Ethiopia

Tags: international-transfer

How can I make global payment from Ethiopia for international services and tradings?

Comment: Welcome to [money.se]. If the question is about how to upgrade wordpress, it is off-topic. If the question is about how to get a trade licence in Ethiopia then it *could* be on-topic, but then you should make it clear in the question (click in the "edit" button to modify it).

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by upgrading your blog

Comment: Is it possible for you to get a trade license? That seems like the easiest way to solve the issue and may even be required in your country to start a business.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you saying you can't buy any software or service online from your country? A blogging platform is a service. The actual end service (Wordpress) is a bit beside the point. It seems this would broadly apply.

Comment: Yes dear friends. I can't. There is rare possibility but practically it  is impossible.It is possible only if I have import-export trade licence. Evenif I am licenced the amount of dollars given by Commercial bank of Ethiopia is limitted.

Answer (score 1):

There is [no legal way](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/africa/ethiopia/money-transfer-from-ethiopia) to transfer money **out** of Ethiopia except as outlined in the [FAQ of the Commercial Bank of Ethiopia](https://www.combanketh.et/InternationalBanking/TradeService.aspx). You would need to start a business and explain to the bank the reason to transfer money out of the country. External trade, done legally, is [documented and regulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_Ethiopia#External_trade).

FAQ:

1. **Eligibility criteria/conditions**

   Customers that request the above products of Trade Service, except guarantee should fulfill the following criteria:

   - Should maintain current account with the bank
   - Should be in the possession of valid trade license for import /export as appropriate or business license or investment or industry license or must exist in the list of budgetary government organizations issued by the National Bank of Ethiopia. In case of non-government organization, certificate issued by the Ministry of Justice, Regional Governments and offices authorized by proclamation.
   - Should have Tax Identification Number(TIN)
   - Should not be reported as delinquent by the NBE
2. The following are major services provided:

   - Documentary credit (L/C): is a written undertaking by a bank given to the seller at a request and/or the instruction of the buyer to make payment or accept and pay bill of exchanging (draft) drawn by the seller up to a stated sum of money within a prescribed time limit and against stipulated documents.

     - Import - available by sight payment/negotiation payment/deferred payment*/acceptance payment*
     - Export - payment available by sight/negotiation/acceptance of bills

     *If approved by the National Bank of Ethiopia
   - Advance payment: is a method through which a seller receives payment from a buyer prior to shipment or the agreed upon goods or rendering the agreed upon service.

     - Import - Payment though bank transfers
     - Export - Payment through bank transfers, traveler cheques, cash (as long as it is declared).

IF you are not a national of Ethiopia things are different, wages can leave the country and tourists are allowed to leave with less than they entered with.